# WPF TabControl overrides TabItem Background?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

```xml
<Window x:Name="Editor" x:Class="Editor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Editor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Editor" Height="450" Width="800" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Icon="src/Assets/Core/Lively.ico" Cursor="Arrow">
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" ScaleY="2"/>
                    <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-133.069" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF360606" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF150303" Offset="0.474"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF2E0606" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF0E0707" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Window.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.207"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.007"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.OpacityMask>
    <Grid x:Name="EditorBody" Background="Transparent">
        <TabControl Height="44" Margin="0,0,0,406" Background="Transparent">
            <TabItem Background="Black" Height="44" Width="150" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Label Content="Untitled note" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the bottom part here; I'm seemingly unable to get the TabItem to react to changes in its `Background` property. It remains white no matter what.

When I move the TabItem out of the TabControl however (via dragging with the Designer), it follows the Background color.

I'm probably just missing a property here, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it as follows.

```
<Grid  x:Name="EditorBody" Background="Transparent">
    <TabControl Height="100" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,406">
        <TabItem Header="Tab A" Background="Red" Foreground="Black">
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="Untitled note" Foreground="White"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab B" Background="Orange" Foreground="Black">
            <Grid></Grid>
        </TabItem >
        <TabItem Header="Tab C" Background="Yellow" Foreground="Black">
            <Grid></Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Please write a comment if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb8022a0-89ba-4753-b2df-6a48e67ca834/how-to-set-tabitem-background-color?forum=wpf
According to the answers to the proposed question at the above link:
"The TabControl binds the content of its ContentPresenter to the content of the selected TabItem. This would explain why the background of the Content is the same as the TabControl and not the TabItem"

Comment: It's not the same as the TabControl. It's white regardless.